# Updating elements in matrix that is field of a document that is nested in another document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, matrix, mongodb-query

Its really hard to formulate my question shortly but here is the position of the matrix in database
(the matrix can have any number of columns/rows and there can be more than one garden):

```
{
  UserId: 5,
  Gardens : [
  {
    Name: "gardenName",
    Plants : [[Array][Array]]
    }
  ]
}
```

Objects in matrix are like this:
*{field1 : val1, field2 : val2, ...}*

How can one update, let's say field1, of an element in Plants matrix using nodejs/mongodb?
I have seen solutions for similar problems but none of them include matrices like this, only arrays using operators $, $[] etc. but I can't see a way to do that here.

Comment: I think field1 can also be present in array2, I would recommend keeping matrix in a separate collection as a document.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution that doesn't need 2 collections(one for matrices and other for users), but is not MongoDB only, as it depends on front-end sending it previous versions of the matrix.

It works like this:

```
let user = req.session.user;

let name = req.body.name;
let gardenMat = req.body.garden;
let i = parseInt(req.body.x);
let j = parseInt(req.body.y);

gardenMat[i][j].state = newState;

db.collection('users').findOneAndUpdate(
    {username : user},
    {$set : {"garden.$[element].garden" : gardenMat}},
    {arrayFilters : [{"element.name" : {$eq : name}}]}
);
```

So, front-end sends whole matrix that it is displaying and that way we get old version of matrix. Then, we update certain fields (1 or more) and with simple use of *findOneAndUpdate* we update matrix field in the document.

The version with two collections is simpler I think because it is not dependant on front-end.